# display date (day, month, year) on x-axis of plot

Tags: r, date, plot, axis

I would like to display the corresponding date on the x-axis. However the date changes on the axis depending on what data is shown in the plot. For example: sometimes it only shows a couple of months if the data is only from 2020 and sometimes it only shows just 2020, 2021 in years and no months. How can I give the command to display only months, only years or both?

My second problem is the change between my x and y-axis. At first they were correct, but now the axises have swapped for some reason. How can I put the date on the x-axis and the distance(km) on y-axis?

My dataset is called `pattern1` and I tried the following below:

```
library(pals)
colors2 <- polychrome(n=36)
library(spatialrisk)

patternDO <- pattern1[pattern1$Transmitter == "A69-1602-59771",]
Loc <- unique(patternDO$Location.Receiver)
plot(patternDO$Date, patternDO$Distance_km, xlim = , ylim = , xlab="Date", ylab="Distance from batch (km)", pch=NA)
legend(x = "topright", inset = c(-0.5,0), legend = Loc, col = colors2, title="Den Oever", cex = 0.5, pch = 16)

for(j in 1:length(Loc)){
  loc.rec <- patternDO[patternDO$Location.Receiver == Loc[j],]
  points(loc.rec$Date, loc.rec$Distance_km, xlim = range(patternDO$Date), pch=18, cex=1.0, col= colors2[j])
}
```

```
structure(list(Day = c("20", "21", "06", "09", "11", "12", "15", 
"09", "11", "04", "07", "08", "19", "04", "05", "13", "15", "16", 
"17", "18", "20", "21", "22", "27", "29", "30", "01", "02", "06", 
"07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "05", "06", "19", "20", "07", 
"11", "12", "14", "15", "16", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", 
"02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "14", "15", "22"), Month = c("05", 
"05", "05", "05", "05", "05", "05", "06", "03", "05", "05", "05", 
"05", "06", "06", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", 
"11", "11", "11", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", 
"12", "01", "01", "01", "01", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", 
"02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", 
"03", "04", "04", "04"), Year = c("2020", "2020", "2021", "2021", 
"2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2020", "2020", "2020", "2020", 
"2020", "2020", "2020", "2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", 
"2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", 
"2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", "2020", 
"2020", "2020", "2020", "2020", "2020", "2020", "2020", "2020", 
"2020", "2020", "2020", "2020", "2020", "2020", "2020", "2020", 
"2020", "2020", "2020", "2020", "2020", "2020", "2020", "2020"
), Location.Receiver = c("Medemblik Ijsselmeer, inlaat", "Medemblik Ijsselmeer, inlaat", 
"Medemblik Ijsselmeer, inlaat", "Medemblik Ijsselmeer, inlaat", 
"Medemblik Ijsselmeer, inlaat", "Medemblik Ijsselmeer, inlaat", 
"Medemblik Ijsselmeer, inlaat", "Medemblik Ijsselmeer, inlaat", 
"Makkum Ijsselmeer", "Makkum Ijsselmeer", "Makkum Ijsselmeer", 
"Makkum Ijsselmeer", "Makkum Ijsselmeer", "Makkum Ijsselmeer", 
"Makkum Ijsselmeer", "Stavoren Ijsselmeer", "Stavoren Ijsselmeer", 
"Stavoren Ijsselmeer", "Stavoren Ijsselmeer", "Stavoren Ijsselmeer", 
"Stavoren Ijsselmeer", "Stavoren Ijsselmeer", "Stavoren Ijsselmeer", 
"Stavoren Ijsselmeer", "Stavoren Ijsselmeer", "Stavoren Ijsselmeer", 
"Stavoren Ijsselmeer", "Stavoren Ijsselmeer", "Stavoren Ijsselmeer", 
"Stavoren Ijsselmeer", "Stavoren Ijsselmeer", "Stavoren Ijsselmeer", 
"Stavoren Ijsselmeer", "Stavoren Ijsselmeer", "Stavoren Ijsselmeer", 
"Stavoren Ijsselmeer", "Stavoren Ijsselmeer", "Stavoren Ijsselmeer", 
"Stavoren Ijsselmeer", "Stavoren Ijsselmeer", "Stavoren Ijsselmeer", 
"Stavoren Ijsselmeer", "Stavoren Ijsselmeer", "Stavoren Ijsselmeer", 
"Stavoren Ijsselmeer", "Stavoren Ijsselmeer", "Stavoren Ijsselmeer", 
"Stavoren Ijsselmeer", "Stavoren Ijsselmeer", "Stavoren Ijsselmeer", 
"Stavoren Ijsselmeer", "Stavoren Ijsselmeer", "Stavoren Ijsselmeer", 
"Stavoren Ijsselmeer", "Stavoren Ijsselmeer", "Stavoren Ijsselmeer", 
"Stavoren Ijsselmeer", "Stavoren Ijsselmeer", "Stavoren Ijsselmeer", 
"Stavoren Ijsselmeer"), Transmitter = c("A69-1602-59773", "A69-1602-59773", 
"A69-1602-59775", "A69-1602-59775", "A69-1602-59773", "A69-1602-59773", 
"A69-1602-59775", "A69-1602-59773", "A69-1602-59774", "A69-1602-59774", 
"A69-1602-59774", "A69-1602-59774", "A69-1602-59774", "A69-1602-59774", 
"A69-1602-59774", "A69-1602-59770", "A69-1602-59770", "A69-1602-59770", 
"A69-1602-59770", "A69-1602-59770", "A69-1602-59770", "A69-1602-59770", 
"A69-1602-59770", "A69-1602-59770", "A69-1602-59770", "A69-1602-59770", 
"A69-1602-59770", "A69-1602-59770", "A69-1602-59770", "A69-1602-59770", 
"A69-1602-59770", "A69-1602-59770", "A69-1602-59770", "A69-1602-59770", 
"A69-1602-59770", "A69-1602-59770", "A69-1602-59770", "A69-1602-59770", 
"A69-1602-59770", "A69-1602-59770", "A69-1602-59770", "A69-1602-59770", 
"A69-1602-59770", "A69-1602-59770", "A69-1602-59770", "A69-1602-59770", 
"A69-1602-59770", "A69-1602-59770", "A69-1602-59770", "A69-1602-59770", 
"A69-1602-59770", "A69-1602-59770", "A69-1602-59770", "A69-1602-59770", 
"A69-1602-59770", "A69-1602-59770", "A69-1602-59770", "A69-1602-59770", 
"A69-1602-59770", "A69-1602-59778"), Batch.location = c("Den Oever", 
"Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", 
"Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", 
"Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", 
"Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", 
"Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", 
"Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", 
"Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", 
"Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", 
"Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", 
"Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", 
"Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", 
"Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever"), BatchNr = c(5, 
5, 7, 7, 5, 5, 7, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 10), Latitude = c(52.73978, 
52.73978, 52.73978, 52.73978, 52.73978, 52.73978, 52.73978, 52.73978, 
53.05562, 53.05562, 53.05562, 53.05562, 53.05562, 53.05562, 53.05562, 
51.87778, 51.87778, 51.87778, 51.87778, 51.87778, 51.87778, 51.87778, 
51.87778, 51.87778, 51.87778, 51.87778, 51.87778, 51.87778, 51.87778, 
51.87778, 51.87778, 51.87778, 51.87778, 51.87778, 51.87778, 51.87778, 
51.87778, 51.87778, 51.87778, 51.87778, 51.87778, 51.87778, 51.87778, 
51.87778, 51.87778, 51.87778, 51.87778, 51.87778, 51.87778, 51.87778, 
51.87778, 51.87778, 51.87778, 51.87778, 51.87778, 51.87778, 51.87778, 
51.87778, 51.87778, 51.87778), Longitude = c(5.14755, 5.14755, 
5.14755, 5.14755, 5.14755, 5.14755, 5.14755, 5.14755, 5.3815, 
5.3815, 5.3815, 5.3815, 5.3815, 5.3815, 5.3815, 5.3611, 5.3611, 
5.3611, 5.3611, 5.3611, 5.3611, 5.3611, 5.3611, 5.3611, 5.3611, 
5.3611, 5.3611, 5.3611, 5.3611, 5.3611, 5.3611, 5.3611, 5.3611, 
5.3611, 5.3611, 5.3611, 5.3611, 5.3611, 5.3611, 5.3611, 5.3611, 
5.3611, 5.3611, 5.3611, 5.3611, 5.3611, 5.3611, 5.3611, 5.3611, 
5.3611, 5.3611, 5.3611, 5.3611, 5.3611, 5.3611, 5.3611, 5.3611, 
5.3611, 5.3611, 5.3611), Date = structure(c(18402, 18403, 18753, 
18756, 18758, 18759, 18762, 18787, 18332, 18386, 18389, 18390, 
18401, 18417, 18418, 18213, 18215, 18216, 18217, 18218, 18220, 
18221, 18222, 18227, 18229, 18230, 18231, 18232, 18236, 18237, 
18238, 18239, 18240, 18241, 18242, 18266, 18267, 18280, 18281, 
18299, 18303, 18304, 18306, 18307, 18308, 18315, 18316, 18317, 
18318, 18319, 18320, 18323, 18324, 18325, 18326, 18327, 18328, 
18366, 18367, 18374), class = "Date"), Distance_km = c(21.6573593129425, 
21.6573593129425, 21.6573593129425, 21.6573593129425, 21.6573593129425, 
21.6573593129425, 21.6573593129425, 21.6573593129425, 27.1352921526802, 
27.1352921526802, 27.1352921526802, 27.1352921526802, 27.1352921526802, 
27.1352921526802, 27.1352921526802, 118.410511308913, 118.410511308913, 
118.410511308913, 118.410511308913, 118.410511308913, 118.410511308913, 
118.410511308913, 118.410511308913, 118.410511308913, 118.410511308913, 
118.410511308913, 118.410511308913, 118.410511308913, 118.410511308913, 
118.410511308913, 118.410511308913, 118.410511308913, 118.410511308913, 
118.410511308913, 118.410511308913, 118.410511308913, 118.410511308913, 
118.410511308913, 118.410511308913, 118.410511308913, 118.410511308913, 
118.410511308913, 118.410511308913, 118.410511308913, 118.410511308913, 
118.410511308913, 118.410511308913, 118.410511308913, 118.410511308913, 
118.410511308913, 118.410511308913, 118.410511308913, 118.410511308913, 
118.410511308913, 118.410511308913, 118.410511308913, 118.410511308913, 
118.410511308913, 118.410511308913, 118.410511308913)), row.names = c(891412L, 
955710L, 1059292L, 1065023L, 948999L, 868059L, 1002935L, 954036L, 
986970L, 966667L, 965406L, 982523L, 967432L, 969213L, 980790L, 
799297L, 801897L, 795265L, 799017L, 803111L, 802007L, 800569L, 
794799L, 804556L, 800332L, 801315L, 803927L, 802759L, 800919L, 
795980L, 793262L, 802643L, 802404L, 792964L, 802448L, 801798L, 
798878L, 801070L, 796056L, 792945L, 799448L, 803204L, 797972L, 
799537L, 802516L, 805170L, 800636L, 791667L, 802820L, 800930L, 
799821L, 802898L, 804767L, 805158L, 795870L, 801961L, 791160L, 
803578L, 803710L, 1231075L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: In `ggplot2`, it has a generally good-enough mechanism to determine good-looking axes when using dates (and timestamps); I don't know that base R functions have as-good a mechanism to do this. I suggest a simple helper function that takes the x-axis range and determines (based on simple heuristics) if it should show years, months, days, or similar. And then output either (a) just the x locations (`Date`) or (b) the x location and a pretty-printed rendition based on the span. For instance (for b), if the span is years, the display might be just `"%Y"`, no need for `"%Y-%m"`, etc.

Comment: (I might be mistaken ... if anybody knows of a `Date`- or `POSIXt`-aware `axisTicks` or similar, please say something!)